# Acessando um pixel em SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Eu estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde eu devo acessar pixel de uma imagem e colocá-los em uma nova matriz em RGB, para isso estou usando a biblioteca SFML, minha dificuldade é na logica, sei que um pixel é o menor ponto de uma imagem e essa biblioteca me da acesso a eles por meio do código:

```
const sf::Uint8* pixels = imagem.getPixelsPtr();
```

Pela a documentação a biblioteca guarda os pixels em um vetor.

O que eu estou fazendo é o seguinte: sabendo a altura e largura dela, estou percorrendo com um laço e tento pegar os pixels!

```
// Descobre o tamanho da imagem
sf::Vector2u tam = imagem.getSize();
int largura = tam.x;
int altura  = tam.y;

for(int i = 0; i < largura ; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < altura; j++)
    {
        ///METODO DA BIBLIOTECA SFML, PARA ACESSAR O PIXEL.
        const sf::Uint8* pixels = imagem.getPixelsPtr();
    }
}
```

Como eu faço para converter essa imagem em RGB e colocá-los em um outro vetor?

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais simples de fazer isso é usando a função [**`getPixel(x, y)`**](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/classsf_1_1Image.php#a8c8460e311dcb00557cb00a81c29163d) de `sf::Image`. Basta chamar ela dentro do seu loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < largura ; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < altura; j++)
    {
        sf::Color px = imagem.getPixel(i, j);
        sf::Uint8 r = px.r;
        sf::Uint8 g = px.g;
        sf::Uint8 b = px.b;
        sf::Uint8 a = px.a;
    }
}
```

Alternativamente (muito melhor em performance), use o [**`getPixelsPtr()`**](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/classsf_1_1Image.php#ac6137a608a9efaae2735c13ff259c214) como sugeriu na pergunta:

```
const sf::Uint8* ptr = imagem.getPixelsPtr();
for(int i = 0; i < largura ; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < altura; j++)
    {
        sf::Uint8 r = ptr[4 * (j * largura + i) + 0];
        sf::Uint8 g = ptr[4 * (j * largura + i) + 1];
        sf::Uint8 b = ptr[4 * (j * largura + i) + 2];
        sf::Uint8 a = ptr[4 * (j * largura + i) + 3];
    }
}
```

Essa função retorna um ponteiro para uma lista de pixels. Cada um composto de 4 componentes, o RGBA. É importante notar que esse ponteiro só é válido enquanto a imagem não for editada. Se qualquer coisa modificar a imagem, essa lista pode ser realocada e movida. Não guarde por mais tempo que o necessário.

Answer (score 1):

Um pixel realmente é o menor ponto de uma imagem, mas o que a biblioteca retorna, através do ponteiro `const sf::Uint8* pixels` são as componentes R, G, B e A dos pixels (de acordo com a [documentação](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1Image.php#ad1594ab4251d6fc833a48dd242918631)).

A cada 4 `Uint8`, você tem um pixel propriamente dito. Assim, se você quiser copiar os pixels para outro vetor, nem precisa utilizar laços manuais, pode utiliza a função `memcpy` do próprio C para isso.

O vetor para onde você deve copiar a imagem precisa ter o tamanho de `4 * largura * altura` bytes:

```
sf::Uint8* novoVetor = new sf::Uint8[4 * largura * altura];
```

Em seguida, basta copiar os bytes do ponteiro retornado pela função `getPixelsPtr()` utilizando o `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(novoVetor, imagem.getPixelsPtr(), 4 * largura * altura);
```

Por questões de desempenho, dê preferência a funções que retornam vários pixels por vez, como `getPixelsPtr()`, em vez de utilizar diversos `getPixel(x, y)`.

Agora, se preferir utilizar um laço criado manualmente, em vez de utilizar o `memcpy`, você pode fazer assim:

```
sf::Uint8* novoVetor = new sf::Uint8[4 * largura * altura];
const sf::Uint8* pixels = imagem.getPixelsPtr();
int tamanho = 4 * largura * altura;
for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
    novoVetor[i] = pixels[i];
}
```

Ainda, se preferir, você pode realizar um `typecast`, e trabalhar com vetor de inteiros. Como cada inteiro do tipo `int`, ou `unsigned int` tem 4 bytes, você pode efetivamente armazenar 1 pixel por elemento do vetor:

```
unsigned int* novoVetor = new unsigned int[largura * altura];
const unsigned int* pixels = (const unsigned int*)imagem.getPixelsPtr();
int tamanho = largura * altura;
for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
    novoVetor[i] = pixels[i];
}
```

Comment: Olá tudo bem @carlosrafaelgn? 
Obrigado pela reposta,desculpa minha iguinorancia ainda estou estudando hehe, mas se eu coloca-se em um matriz ao invez de um vetor o código seria mais ou menos assim?!

`int mat[largura][altura];
memcpy(mat, imagem.getPixelsPtr(), 4 * largura * altura); `

não querendo me estender muito, mas uma outra parte do projeto é mudar os pixels capiturados por caracteres, o uso desse metodo não iria me complicar mais a frente?!
Att

Comment: Nossa...! Não captei, mesmo, a ideia de mudar os pixels por caracteres... :(

Comment: Olá, esse projeto é para um código que ira criar uma ASCIIART em c++, pois isso devo além de obter os pixels converte-los para caracteres antes de coloca-los em uma nova matriz(a nova imagem).

Comment: Bem, nesse caso, a conversa é outra... ;) Dá uma olhada nesses 3 links aqui: [ASCII Art no SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394882/how-do-ascii-art-image-conversion-algorithms-work), [ASCII Art no CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20435/Using-C-To-Generate-ASCII-Art-From-An-Image) e uma lib para isso [AA-lib](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/)

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra solução é a seguinte:

Verifique o tamanho da imagem original, antes do converter.

```
sf::Uint32 sz = img.getSize().x * img.getSize().y;
```

Crie uma estrutura para armazenar os pixels em RGB.
Pode ser um vetor de `sf::Uint8`.
Mas, eu usei um `std::vector<sf::Uint8>`.

```
// Vetor que armazenará os pixels.
std::vector<sf::Uint8> rgb_pixels;
rgb_pixels.reserve(sz * 3); // reserva o espaço do tamanho da imagem RGB.
```

Por fim, copie os pixels da imagem original e armazene no vetor RGB.

```
// O ponteiro dos pixel originais em RGBA.
const sf::Uint8* img_pixels = img.getPixelsPtr();

// Armazena os pixels RGBA em um std::vector RGB:
for(sf::Uint32 i = 0u; i < (sz * 4); i += 4)
{
    // Pega o pixel da imagem original em RGBA na mesma posição que será copiada.
    const sf::Uint8* rgba = reinterpret_cast<const sf::Uint8*>(&img_pixels[i]);

    // Armazena no vetor de RGB
    rgb_pixels.push_back(rgba[0]); // r
    rgb_pixels.push_back(rgba[1]); // g
    rgb_pixels.push_back(rgba[2]); // b

    // Não armazena o rgba[3] pois você quer RGB, não RGBA.
    // rgb_pixels.push_back(rgba[3]); // a
}
```

Finalmente, se você quiser acessar o ponteiro em `const sf::Uint8*` é só chamar:

```
const sf::Uint8* rgb_ptr = rgb_pixels.data();
```

Comment: Eu colocaria uma ressalva na comparação do `for`, `i < sz * 4`. Se o compilador não for muito esperto, ele fará essa multiplicação toda vez antes de comparar. Outro detalhe é o uso de `Uint64 i` como contador... Nesse caso, acho *overkill* e meio desperdício de memória/processamento. Um último detalhe, é que no comentário do código você diz `Convertendo para Uint32*`, mas não aparece `Uint32*` em lugar nenhum do resto do código.

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn Obrigado pelo aviso. Essas informações a mais foi em decorrência do reaproveitamento de um código antigo meu que usava `Uint32*`, mas acabei refazendo para ficar mais simples.